# Is it possible to automatically convert integers keys to string for all Immutable.js object?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I wish there were an easy way to forbid integer's keys for all immutable js keys, and automatically convert integers to strings when accessing them.

```js
var a = Immutable.Map({})
a = a.set("1", "string");
a = a.set(1, "integer");
console.log(a.size);     // 2
console.log(a);          // {"1": "string", 1: integer}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Weird thing is its not showing in snippet but if you check in console, entries has 2 entries

Comment: yeah, snippet log is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/):

> While designed to bring these powerful functional concepts to JavaScript, it presents an Object-Oriented API familiar to Javascript engineers and closely mirroring that of Array, Map, and Set

So there is a difference in `set[1]` and set["1"]. But if you wish to have string values only, you can have a custom wrapper that will add stringified version of keys.

Following is the sample:

```js
Immutable.Map.prototype.addMyEntry = function(key, value){
  return this.set(key.toString(), value);
}

var a = Immutable.Map({})
a = a.addMyEntry("1", "string");
a = a.addMyEntry(1, "integer");
console.log(a.size)
console.log(a)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's not enough to wrap only one function :( `setIn`, `get`, `getIn` have to be wrapped as well and probably there are other places in API where it makes difference between passing integer or string.

Comment: @LiubomyrMykhalchenko yes thats true but there is a difference between numeric and non-numeric keys. Arrays have numeric indexes where as maps have non-numeric keys. Its your specific requirement where you wish to treat them same. For such cases, you will need to create wrapper functions. Also my answer is just a sample of how you can achieve it.